# How to replace elements in python list by values from dictionary if list-element = dict-key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, matching

input:

```
[yellow, red, green,  blue]

{green:go, yellow:attention, red:stay}
```

how to make new list:

```
[attention, stay, go, blue]
```

are there way to make it with lambda?

Comment: You mean with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) inside a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = ["yellow", "red", "green",  "blue"]
dic = {"green":"go", "yellow":"attention", "red":"stay"}
res = [dic.get(e, e) for e in lst]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['attention', 'stay', 'go', 'blue']
```

Comment: thanks, bro, perfect work

Answer (score 2):

The only way to use lambda I can think of is using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```py
l = ['yellow', 'red', 'green',  'blue']
d = {'green': 'go', 'yellow': 'attention', 'red': 'stay'}
out = map(lambda x: d.get(x, x), l)
print(list(out))
```

**Result**

```py
['attention', 'stay', 'go', 'blue']
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought without lambda it's not possible in one line, but first commet made it